# Dockerfile Error while giving RUN command

Tags: dockerfile, yum, centos8

I am trying to learn Docker and I am on Oracle VMware on CentOS8. I am trying to build a Dockerfile. Here is the content of the file Dockerfile:

```
FROM centos

RUN yum -y install httpd
```

When I build, it throws the error below:

```
[arijhit@localhost docker-images]$ docker build --tag centos_apache:v1 .

Sending build context to Docker daemon  2.048kB

Step 1/2 : FROM centos
 ---> 0d120b6ccaa8

Step 2/2 : RUN yum -y install httpd
 ---> Running in 1f20ba141039
CentOS-8 - AppStream                            0.0  B/s |   0  B     00:30    

Errors during downloading metadata for repository 'AppStream':
  - Curl error (6): Couldn't resolve host name for http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=8&arch=x86_64&repo=AppStream&infra=container [Could not resolve host: mirrorlist.centos.org]

Error: Failed to download metadata for repo 'AppStream': Cannot prepare internal mirrorlist: Curl error (6): Couldn't resolve host name for http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=8&arch=x86_64&repo=AppStream&infra=container [Could not resolve host: mirrorlist.centos.org]**

The command '/bin/sh -c yum -y install httpd' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

Can someone please help rectify this?

Edit:

Hi @Uberhumus Here is the response from CentOS docker image for the commands you said

```
[arijhit@localhost ~]$ docker run -t -d centos 60566bb1a2ef808c59c0374c0e9753bc26f0098c8b54c438e7742af418beae3a

[arijhit@localhost ~]$ docker p
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE             COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS NAMES
60566bb1a2ef        centos              "/bin/bash"              20 seconds ago      Up 8 seconds                            laughing_greider
5d3efb03c67a        nginx:alpine        "/docker-entrypoint.…"   6 minutes ago       Up 5 minutes        80/tcp              kind_tesla

[arijhit@localhost ~]$ docker exec -it laughing_greider /bin/bash

[root@60566bb1a2ef /]# ping 8.8.8.8
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=1 ttl=115 time=31.4 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=2 ttl=115 time=168 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=3 ttl=115 time=47.3 ms 
^C
--- 8.8.8.8 ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 3 received, 0% packet loss, time 5ms 
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 31.357/82.241/168.110/61.064 ms

[root@60566bb1a2ef /]# yum check-update
Failed to set locale, defaulting to C.UTF-8
CentOS-8 - AppStream 0.0  B/s |   0  B     00:30
Errors during downloading metadata for repository 'AppStream':
  - Curl error (6): Couldn't resolve host name for http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=8&arch=x86_64&repo=AppStream&infra=container [Could not resolve host: mirrorlist.centos.org] Error: Failed to download metadata for repo 'AppStream': Cannot prepare internal mirrorlist: Curl error (6): Couldn't resolve host name for http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=8&arch=x86_64&repo=AppStream&infra=container [Could not resolve host: mirrorlist.centos.org]

[root@60566bb1a2ef /]# yum -y install httpd
Failed to set locale, defaulting to C.UTF-8
CentOS-8 - AppStream 0.0  B/s |   0  B     00:30
Errors during downloading metadata for repository 'AppStream':
  - Curl error (6): Couldn't resolve host name for http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=8&arch=x86_64&repo=AppStream&infra=container [Could not resolve host: mirrorlist.centos.org] Error: Failed to download metadata for repo 'AppStream': Cannot prepare internal mirrorlist: Curl error (6): Couldn't resolve host name for http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=8&arch=x86_64&repo=AppStream&infra=container [Could not resolve host: mirrorlist.centos.org]
```

Comment: What have you tried doing? specifically, did you try running "docker run -it centos /bin/sh" and in it running "yum -y install httpd"? It will at the very least let you see the error.

Comment: is your host running behind a corporate proxy or anything like that?

Comment: @Uberhumus - I have tried running yum update -y with root access. Since I am creating docker file and need to build it, should I be putting "docker run -it centos /bin/sh" inside the docker file. Or you want me to run this as a command line before building the Dockerfile.

Comment: @agentsmith - its my personal laptop, so no corporate firewall or any proxy. I am running Windows 10 as host on which I am running CentOS through OracleVM. So the same Wifi to which my host Windows is connected, the same is being used to provide internet connectivity to my virtual machine.

Comment: @arijhit, can you try these and report the results please:
In a running CentOS docker try ping 8.8.8.8 
If that works try 'yum check-update' and then 'yum -y install httpd'

Comment: @Uberhumus - I am not being able to create CentOS docker container. Even though no error is coming, somehow it is exiting when I give the command 'docker run -d centos'. Dont know why. But I tried running al the commands you gave through command line of the( VMware) CentOS. All ran perfectly. yum check-update updated the yum. Only 'yum -y install httpd' needed to be run as a root user. Running the dockerfile still gives the same error. What am I missing?

Comment: I didn't understand, you finished a build with no errors but now it doesn't work when try running `docker run -d centos?` And did you run the commands I suggested in a docker container (Not a VM)?

Comment: My bad, I ran it at the command line of my CentOS machine. Not a docker container. I could fire up a docker container now using 'docker run -t -d centos'. I will report in a few mins...

Comment: @Uberhumus - any thoughts on what can be done? I am still facing the issue. Is it not happening at your end? Or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: @arijhit It is not happening on my end. I'm guessing it's an issue with the way your docker networks are defined, but I'd like to check more before I answer. I'll probably get to it after work.

Answer (score 2):

Dear All the following solved my problem.

```
firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=trusted --add-interface=docker0

firewall-cmd --reload
```

Found it here:
https://forums.centos.org/viewtopic.php?f=54&t=74270

Many thanks to everyone here...

Answer (score 1):

I tried to build your Dockerfile and I've gotten an error too, albeit a different one.

Below are working Dockerfiles for CentOS 7 and CentOS 8 respectively:

```
FROM centos:7

RUN yum -y install httpd

EXPOSE 80

ENTRYPOINT [ "/usr/sbin/httpd" ]
CMD [ "-D", "FOREGROUND"]
```

and

```
FROM centos:8

RUN yum clean all && \
    yum -y update && \
    yum -y install httpd

EXPOSE 80

ENTRYPOINT [ "/usr/sbin/httpd" ]
CMD [ "-D", "FOREGROUND"]
```

Let me know if either of those works for you.

Edit:

I put the prebuilt images [here](https://hub.docker.com/r/forinil/centos-httpd/tags) if you need them.

Edit 2:

If the above Dockerfiles do not build for you, then it's most likely a problem with Docker's DNS. Please follow the steps in [this article](https://development.robinwinslow.uk/2016/06/23/fix-docker-networking-dns/) to verify that hypothesis and possibly resolve the problem.

Comment: None of these worked. I edited your comment to give the entire output, somehow that post did not get approved. I cannot post the details in the comments box. But no, the 'RUN yum' command gave error for both the versions. Let me know if you have anything in mind. Also since I am trying to create image file from Dockerfile, hence I did not download your prebuilt images.

Comment: Your edit was rejected, because you're supposed put any and all info you have on your issue in your question - that includes results of running any commands provided in possible answers.